# How to find the trigger that caused the update in React 16?

Tags: reactjs, debugging

I've recently upgraded to fiber. In 15, when a component updates, the update stack trace looks like this

```
component1Update
...react framework stuff
  component2Update
  ...react framework stuff
    component3Update
    setState
    onClick() <-- Aha!
```

How do you find the origin of update in Fiber (React 16)?

Comment: How do you get that stack trace in the first place?

Comment: @hackape Ah forgot to mention, from a debugger statement in render method.

Comment: You should see why with https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render ?

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41004631/trace-why-a-react-component-is-re-rendering

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend looking up the node that is being constantly updated in react-profiler, and then decorate that component with https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render this should tell you why did it update.