# How to detect rerenders in React JS correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rerender, virtual-dom, react-devtools

Let's say we have a parent component and multiple functional child components. I want to clearly know if the parent re-renders does the child re-renders or not.

After going through a few articles I came to know there are 3 ways we can detect rerenders. (Let me know if there are more ways.)

**1. Put a `console.log` in the child component.**

**2. Use Chrome paint flashing option in the settings.**

[image]

**3. Use React dev tool**

[image]

Do all these ways are correct to know if the component really rerenders? Because it doesn't seem to be work correctly with React.memo.

When I am wrapping the Child component with React.memo it does not print `console.log`, when the parent component rerenders which is correct. But still with chrome and react dev tools highlights the child component as if it rerendered.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-cloud-iv0rv 
(If we add a new car still the static component is highlighted in green, but as per Memo, it should not rerender.)

Now my doubt, Is paint flashing does not work correctly or React.memo having issues?

Comment: are you sure am able to see a log being printed in your sandbox console...

Comment: @pavankumar, For first render it will print for sure, but if the component wrapped with React.memo , it does not print console.log for subsequent renders when the Add button is clicked.

Comment: Related & helpful - [Trace why a React component is re-rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51082563/104380)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Reason

If you use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo), you need to use it **from parent down to all the child** till the end.

Since [React.PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) share the same feature with `React.memo`, you can find those explanation in the document as below.

> Furthermore, React.PureComponent’s shouldComponentUpdate() skips prop updates for the whole component subtree. **Make sure all the children components are also “pure”**.

#### Result

By changing parent component `Cars` to memo

```js
// Before
export default Cars;
// After
export default React.memo(Cars);
```

You could find the `react-dev-tools` in chrome will only show the parent component re-rendered this time as well as no child `console.log` fired, which is correct. (Compare to previous, all the child also got highlighted)

Before
[image]

After
[image]

#### Conclusion

Both `console.log` and `react-dev-tools` worked well, you may just need to implement in a proper way following your demand.

Comment: `you need to use it from parent down to all the child till the end.` was the most important concept that I missed. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. Indeed it helped me to get a clear picture how to use memo.