# React: How to prevent re-rendering child components in `map`?

Tags: reactjs, array-map, rerender, usecallback, react-memo

I tried to boil down the problem into an example as simple as possible:

We have a list of child components, each called `NumChoice`, each representing a number. `NumChoice` is wrapped in `React.memo`. In the parent component, we have an array of booleans, `choices`, each corresponding to one of the child components `NumChoice`. At first, all the elements of `choices` are `false`. To render the child components, we iterate through `choices`, and for each choice, generate the corresponding child component `NumChoice`. We define a function `chooseDivisibles` in the parent component, using `useCallback` that is called from each child component `NumChoice`. `chooseDivisibles` takes the index of the `NumChoice` who called it and changes the corresponding element of `choices` to `true`. Each `NumChoice` has a "red" background color if its corresponding element in `choices` is `true`, otherwise, its background color is "white".

The complete code is available at:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-rerender-l4e3c?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Wrapping `NumChoice` in `React.memo` and `chooseDivisibles` in `useCallback`, we expected to only rerender `NumChoice` components whose corresponding element of `choices` changes but React re-renders them all. `chooseDivisibles` is wrapped in `useCallback`, which lists no dependency other than `setChoices`. Also, `NumChoice` is wrapped in `React.memo` and it should only rerender if the specified props change, but they do not, and changing `choices` should not have any effect on rerendering `NumChoice`. If we exclude checking the equality of `chooseDivisibles` in previous and next props, it works as expected, but I argue that the comparison of previous and next `chooseDivisibles` should not affect rerendering `NumChoice` because it is wrapped in `useCallback`and does not depend on `choices`. How can we prevent re-rendering the `NumChoice` components whose `props` are not changed?

Comment: Before you added the `prevProps.chooseDivisibles === nextProps.chooseDivisiles` everything seemed to be working fine, the profiler wasn't showing components whose props remained the same re-render.

Comment: I think your suggestion does not solve the issue because if we change the equalities to `(prevProps, nextProps) => prevProps === nextProps`, it does rerender all the components. Considering that `chooseDivisibles` is wrapped in `useCallback`, which lists no dependency other than `setChoices`, changing the state should not change `chooseDivisibles` and should not rerender `NumChoice` If you try the same thing without using `map` through an array, this issue does not happen. Please look at the new code that I just saved.

Comment: As far as I know, React already (shallow) compares the previous props with the new props object, so doing `prevProps === newProps` is superfluous, and actually I believe it's wrong, since the result will always be false regardless if you do it that way, as objects are pass-by-reference.

Comment: @eMontielG Your answer is right. Thank you. Please post it and I'll accept is as the correct answer. To address your concern, I changed `chooseDivisibles={event => chooseDivisibles(idx)}` to `chooseDivisibles={chooseDivisibles}` and replaced the function call inside `NumChoice` to `onClick={event => props.chooseDivisibles(props.num)}`. Then, I compared `prevProps.num === nextProps.num &&
    prevProps.choice === nextProps.choice &&
    prevProps.chooseDivisibles === nextProps.chooseDivisibles` and it works as expected.

Comment: By the way, I think I found your issue, you should also be memoizing the component that is looping the choices.

Comment: @eMontielG I disagree. The parent component should definitely change when its state `choices` changes.

Comment: Not really quite sure but I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60388915/11938059) and tried it myself, and it does stop child components from being highlighted when using the component profiler. [Have a look](https://5j7hy.csb.app/), and the [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-how-to-prevent-re-rendering-child-components-in-map-5j7hy). Just check the 'Highlight updates when components render' option. What's weird is that if you record the graph won't show the components being re-rendered regardless. I can't answer since I'm at a loss as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ah I see that in `NumChoice.js` we're also asserting `prevProps.chooseDivisibles === nextProps.chooseDivisibles`, which is always `false`, since `chooseDivisibles={event => chooseDivisibles(idx)}` generates a new function every time

If you remove `prevProps.chooseDivisibles === nextProps.chooseDivisibles`, it will only re-render the affected ones!

Comment: I think your suggestion does not solve the issue because if we change the equalities to `(prevProps, nextProps) => prevProps === nextProps`, it does rerender all the components. Considering that `chooseDivisibles` is wrapped in `useCallback`, which lists no dependency other than `setChoices`, changing the state should not change `chooseDivisibles` and should not rerender `NumChoice` If you try the same thing without using `map` through an array, this issue does not happen.

Comment: To address your concern, I changed `chooseDivisibles={event => chooseDivisibles(idx)}` to `chooseDivisibles={chooseDivisibles}` and replaced the function call inside `NumChoice` to `onClick={event => props.chooseDivisibles(props.num)}`, but it still rerenders all the `NumChoice` components.

Comment: Hey @1man Sorry I meant we could just comment out asserting the function. Like so:

`(prevProps, nextProps) =>
    prevProps.num === nextProps.num &&
    prevProps.choice === nextProps.choice
    // prevProps.chooseDivisibles === nextProps.chooseDivisibles <-- comment this out`

forked example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-how-to-prevent-re-rendering-child-components-in-map-j4tr5

Comment: We found the solution, but we should not comment our `prevProps.chooseDivisibles === nextProps.chooseDivisibles` because `chooseDivisibles` is wrapped in `useCallback`, which prevents changing the function object when `choices` change. So, we don't need to comment out that comparison. However, if we comment it out and for some other reason `chooseDivisibles` changes, we do want to rerender `NumChoice`.

Comment: Ah that's great to hear! Thanks for the update 

I just updated the example to separate some concerns in `<App />`, so we could simplify the interface of `<NumChoice />` and make its memo function more straight forward

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-how-to-prevent-re-rendering-child-components-in-map-j4tr5

Please let me know what you think!