# Javascript map method not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, array-map

What cause printing every array index twice time using map method. Does component is double rendered? Why it working like that?

```
import React from 'react';
    
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'john' },
  { id: 2, name: 'peter' },
  { id: 3, name: 'susan' },
  { id: 4, name: 'anna' },
];
    
const UseStateArray = () => {
  const [people,setPeople] = React.useState(data)

  return <>
  {
    people.map((person)=>{
      console.log(person);
    })
  }
  </>;
};
```

My output in console is:

```
{id: 1, name: "john"}
{id: 2, name: "peter"}
{id: 3, name: "susan"}
{id: 4, name: "anna"}
{id: 1, name: "john"}
{id: 2, name: "peter"}
{id: 3, name: "susan"}
{id: 4, name: "anna"}
```

Comment: not able to reproduce

Comment: Unless you show your full [mcve], there is no way of telling how many times your full app, or the subtree that includes `<UseStateArray/>`, gets rendered. Just dropping this code into a minimal example with an `<App/>` that only returns <UseStateArray/> shows things doing exactly what you'd expect, rendering only once. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-rbtj6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at this codesandbox example with your code you can see on the console tab that the console log is happening only once https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-hill-0k32k?file=/src/App.js

Most likely the parent component on which you are rendering this component is causing a re-render that's why the console.log appear twice.

[image: showing console log sample]

I find this stackoverflow answer very useful to track what property change is causing the parent component to re-render [Trace why a React component is re-rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41004631/trace-why-a-react-component-is-re-rendering)

Comment: I removed <React.StrictMode> tag from index.js and now console.log appear only once :-)