# Why does the React component render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a rather complicated React app. The problem I am facing is that when a link is click on in the navbar the navbar re-renders. Obviously this is a sign that the app is doing unnecessary rendering. The navbar exists in a "header" component. This "header" should be fixed. But it is getting called numerous times. What is the recommended way to tell WHY a component renders. I can think of numerous reasons and I would like to start eliminating them to cut down on unnecessary renders. The component could be

- Changing internal state (via useState)
- useEffect
- subscribed to "external" state via useSelect
- have props change

There may be others. How do I tell WHY a component renders?

Comment: Props and  state change in the component or parent will make it re-render. Can you please share the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There (apparently) is no easy way to tell why a component renders, probably because it inherently requires deep comparison (at least to cover all cases), which can be an expensive operation.

But there are many tools and workarounds.

- use the [React dev tools](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/main/packages/react-devtools-extensions) (helps, but doesn't show *why* something renders)
- temporarily add a useEffect to observe specific values
- write a hook that can observe several specific values at once
- install [some node package](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=why%20component%20renders)
- check out [trace-why-a-react-component-is-re-rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41004631/trace-why-a-react-component-is-re-rendering)