# What is the point of re-rendering the compnonets that didn't have change in their state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state, react-rendering

I have the main component with a state and a static component inside. When the state changes, the main component is re-rendered, which makes complete sense, but the static component is re-rendered too.

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

function StaticComponent (){
  console.log('re-rendering static component (why?)')

  return <i>Nothing non-static in here</i>
}

function App() {
  console.log('re-rendering App')
  const [state, setState] = useState(0)
  return (
    <>
      {state}<br />
      <button onClick={() => setState((state) => state + 1)}>+</button><br />
      <StaticComponent/>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

What's the point of re-rendering the static component if there is no change in props or state? I came up with a workaround by writing it the following way (and it really worked, unexpectedly for me):

```js
{useMemo(() => <StaticComponent/>, [])}
```

But it's pretty obvious that this workaround is not the solution anyone would want to use. But why don't React developers implement something similar for checking if there was a state change in a specific component before re-rendering it?

Comment: `React.memo()` can be used to stop rerendering of your child components if its props don’t change

Comment: Re-render not only depends on state, but also on props, redux and context. Check all those and you will know why its re-rendering. 
please check this thread `https://stackoverflow.com/a/65425731/6162420`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static component is declared in the component whose state has changed. It's as simple as that.

This structure would prevent the static component from being re-rendered:

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nrrf9x?description=A%20create-react-app%20project%20based%20on%20react%20and%20react-dom&file=src%2FApp.js&title=React%20Starter)

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function StaticComponent (){
  console.log('re-rendering static component (why?)')

  return <i>Nothing non-static in here</i>
}

function App({children}) {
  console.log('re-rendering App')
  const [state, setState] = useState(0)
  return (
    <>
      {state}<br />
      <button onClick={() => setState((state) => state + 1)}>+</button><br />
      {children}
    </>
  )
}

export default () => <App><StaticComponent/></App>
```

Important to note you should do your best to not care how many times something gets rendered, it's mostly an implementation detail and caring about it is anti-declarative (which is what makes React so simple).

Only care when you have performance issues and not before.